# Is possible compute the bandwidth of a Narrowband Twin-T Passive Notch Filter?

Tags: filter, passive-filter, filtering

Exist any function of R and C, for calculate f1 and f2 at figure below?

[image]

Comment: Your attenuation graph has an 'impossible' shape. Search for some correct curves for a notch, redraw it, and then specifiy what sort of bandwidth you mean. Some people will opt for the -3dB points, but with a notch, -20 or -40dB is a more common spec point. Like [this](http://www.circuitstoday.com/band-stop-filter) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is possible compute the bandwidth of a Narrowband Twin-T Passive Notch
>   Filter?

[image]
[image]

The above is the generalized transfer function for a twin T notch filter taken from [here](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/TwinTCRkeisan.htm) (which also provides a useful calculator. If you want the 3 dB frequencies you can rejig the formula and make it simpler because in your equations the resistors are either R or 2R. Ditto the capacitors.

Then solve for the 3 dB points and compute the bandwidth of the notch.

The picture of the response looks like this (R=1 kohm, C = 1nF): -

[image]

And not like what you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation around this 3-energy-storing-element circuit (3rd-order system) can be carried out with different techniques: the brute-force algebra using KVL and KCL or the fast-analytical circuits techniques or FACTs described [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). The KVL and KCL techniques will obviously work and using Thévenin and Superposition is a possibility. However, ordering the final equation under a friendly form from which you can extract the resonant frequency and, later on, the required bandwidth is another story. For instance, the formula kindly provided by Monsieur Andy aka is analytically correct by but does not fit a *low-entropy* format as promoted by the late Dr. Middlebrook. The *low-entropy* format combines poles and zeros under a well-ordered polynomial form which lets you exploit the circuit and tune it to your needs. Without proper factorization in which a resonant frequency and a quality factor appear, there is no way you can determine the component values for a given \$f_0\$ and \$Q\$. A typical *low-entropy* expression describing this twin-T notch filter would be given by:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+a_1s+a_2s^2+a_3s^3}{1+b_1s+b_2s^2+b_3s^3}\$.

The leading term \$H_0\$ is determined for \$s=0\$: open all capacitors and check the transfer function linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$. With this simple arrangement, you find \$H_0=1\$. Then, the determination of the \$b_i\$ terms will require to find the resistance offered by the capacitors connecting terminals when they are temporarily disconnected from the circuit. For this exercise, the excitation \$V_{in}\$ is reduced to 0 V and replaced by a short circuit. For \$b_1\$, you will sum the time constants obtained in this configuration: "look" at the resistance driving \$C_1\$ while the two other capacitors are removed. Do the same for \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$. The obtained resistance multiplied by the involved capacitor gives the time constant \$\tau\$ you want. At the end, you have \$b_1=\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3\$.

For the second-order term \$b_2\$, you consider pairs: short capacitor \$C_1\$ while looking at the resistance driving capacitor \$C_2\$: you have determined \$\tau_{12}\$. Then short capacitor \$C_1\$ while looking at the resistance driving capacitor \$C_3\$: you have determined \$\tau_{13}\$. Finally, short capacitor \$C_2\$ while looking at the resistance driving capacitor \$C_3\$: you have determined \$\tau_{23}\$. Combine and sum these values to form \$b_2=\tau_1\tau_{12}+\tau_1\tau_{13}+\tau_2\tau_{23}\$.

For the final lap, turn \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ in high-frequency state (replace them by a short circuit as we did before) and determine the resistance driving \$C_3\$ in this mode. You have \$\tau_{123}\$ and \$b_3=\tau_1\tau_{12}\tau_{123}\$. I have gathered all the steps in the below drawing and you can realize that I obtained all the resistances by inspection: no algebra, just small sketches for which you infer the resistance value by "looking" through the capacitor's connecting terminals. If you detect a mistake at the end (a deviation from the reference curve or simulation), just review and correct the guilty sketch. No need to swear and restart from scratch as with KVL and KCL applied to the entire circuit:

[image]

The numerator terms can be obtained following a similar approach but this time, the excitation is back in place. The exercise will now consist of determining the resistance offered by the energy-storing element connecting terminals while the output is 0 V. In other words, you will connect a current test generator \$I_T\$ across the considered capacitor and will tweak it until the output voltage \$V_{out}\$ is 0 V or *nulled*. Because you now excite the circuit with two sources, \$V_{in}\$ and \$I_T\$, this is called a null double injection or NDI. It looks kind of complicated but it is not as shown in the below sketch. I want to determine the resistance offered by \$C_1\$'s terminals when the output is 0 V.

[image]

The output voltage is 0 V (this is not a short circuit but rather a virtual ground) and there is no current flowing through \$R_2\$. Therefore, you also have 0 V across the current source. The resistance offered by \$C_1\$'s terminals is therefore \$\frac{0}{I_T}=0\;\Omega\$. The first time constant with a \$N\$ for numerator as a subscript is thus \$\tau_{1N}=C_1\cdot0=0\$. Repeat the exercise for \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ and you should find \$\tau_{2N}=C_2R_3\$ and \$\tau_{3N}=C_3R_3\$. Carry on the exercise and you should obtain the complete transfer function given by (please note the brute-force expression in the right side to test the final result):

[image]

You can now substitute the component values as given in the application example and you obtain a much simpler formula leading to the definition of a quality factor \$Q\$ and a resonant frequency \$f_0\$:

[image]

All expressions in the Mathcad sheet lead to the exact same results. From the final expression, you extract the magnitude which is defined as:

\$|H(\omega)|=\frac{Q(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)}{\sqrt{(Q\omega_0^2-Q\omega^2)^2+(\omega\omega_0)^2}}\$.

You now look for the \$\omega\$ roots satisfying \$|H(\omega)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ and you find the two following -3-dB frequencies:

\$\omega_L=\frac{\omega_0\left(\sqrt{4Q^2+1}-1\right)}{2Q}\$

\$\omega_H=\frac{\omega_0\left(\sqrt{4Q^2+1}+1\right)}{2Q}\$

which give you:

[image]

and if you replace \$Q\$ and \$\omega_0\$ with their respective definitions, you obtain:

\$f_L\approx\frac{0.0188}{RC}\$

\$f_H\approx\frac{0.3371}{RC}\$

I'm done for the day! : )